# Have to "Reload This Script" in AutoHotkey for some programs to pickup remappings

Tags: autohotkey

I have a very simple `AutoHotkey.ahk` file, where I remap `Capslock` to `Esc` and `Esc` to `Capslock` (swapping the keys):

```
Capslock::Esc
Esc::Capslock
```

However, this doesn't work in games like Battlefield 4 or League of Legends. It simply does not do anything.

However, I can press `Reload This Script` in AutoHotkey, and the remapping will start working in those games. It does however work in other games without the need to reload the script first.

I hope you can help me. I would really like this to just work, instead of manually reloading the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `#IfWinActive` directive so that those hotkeys only work in the programs you want - then you don't need to ever reload.

Check in the documentation for "Context-sensitive hotkeys" (under "hotkey" in the index).  Here is an example from the documentation:

> #IfWinActive, ahk_class Notepad ^a::MsgBox You pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> while Notepad is active. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> in any other window will pass the
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> keystroke to that window.
>   #c::MsgBox You pressed Win-C while Notepad is active.

But I think I know why it begins to "not work".  It may be that certain programs set those keys as hotkeys.  Whenever you start those programs they set their own hotkeys and it overrides your script.  You see, the hotkey combination belongs to whatever program sets it last.  When you reload the script, it resets your script as having the authourity.

So if you want the script to never be overridden, and you don't want to manually reload it, find out what programs the combinations don't work in, and use `ifwinactive` to reload your script using autohotkey's `reload` command.

Comment: I want those keymaps I listed. I have the script running, but the keymappings don't work for some games. They do work on the desktop. After I reload the script (that is already running) the keymappings will work in the game (aswell on the desktop). Hope that explains my problem.

Comment: Did you check out the directive in the documentation?  It IS for keymappings.  It makes them work for the programs you want and not for the programs you don't want.

Comment: All programs?  Not just the games?

Comment: Nope! Everywhere. And this is where the problem occurs. Not all games pickup my keymaps. I think some games override default keymaps.

Comment: Can you give me a working example of let's say everytime I open Notepad or Chrome, that it will reload AutoHotkey once? I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried a bunch of things, and ended up reinstalling my computer - that made it work. I am not sure what was the problem.